# Laravel testing: coordinate http-request and controller

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-testing, phpunit

In the below test we (the humbly well my I am) need to make sure that `$utmSource` class field received correct value.

```
<?php

class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

  public function testHttpRequestAndControllerCoordination() {

    $response = $this->call('GET', '/')->json([utm_source => 'Google']);
    $topPageController = new TopPageController();
    $topPageController->renderTopPage();

    $this->assertAttributeSame('Google', 'utm_source', $topPageController);
  }
}

class TopPageController extends Controller {

    private $utmSource;

    public function renderTopPage(){
        $this->utmSource = request()->utm_source;
    }
}
```

Off course, this test will not pass, because `$response` and `$topPageController` are independent, so `$utmSource` will be `null`. How we can relate `$response` and `$topPageController`?

Comment: Make a different method (or modify your current one) that accepts the `utm_source` as a parameter. That way you decouple it from the request and are able to test it

Comment: I guess you need to bind the controller to the test-case before you call "GET".

Comment: @hakre, thank you for the comment. Please, give me the link to some example.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any example at hand (otherwise I would have shared that for sure, I'm not mean), it's just what I can hardly imagine which is why I guessed that.Nothing in Laravell docs about controller testing?

Comment: @hakre, almost nothing for Laravel 5.6 ...